# How would I implement entry based percentage stop losses?

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=5

strategy("3 Minute", overlay=true)

// Add momentum indicator
source = close
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
mom = ta.mom(source, length)

mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = ta.sma(source, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(source, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
buyEntry = ta.crossover(source, lower)
sellEntry = ta.crossunder(source, upper)
if (ta.crossover(source, lower))
    strategy.entry("Buy Calls", strategy.long, oca_name="BollingerBands", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="Buy Calls")
else
    strategy.cancel(id="BBandLE")
if (ta.crossunder(source, upper))
    strategy.entry("Buy Puts", strategy.short, oca_name="BollingerBands", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="Buy Puts")
else
    strategy.cancel(id="BBandSE")

//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)

// Add plot for momentum
plot(mom, title="Momentum", color=color.blue)
```

I tried and its not that im getting an error, it just doesn't seem to affect anything.
I just need help implementing a stop loss based off entry, not a trailing stop loss.

Comment: Where is the exit in your code? I don't see any percentage based exit orders.

Comment: Sorry I removed it cuz It just wasn't working lol

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `strategy.position_avg_price` built-in variable to get your average position price and then calculate your take profit and stop loss based on that.

Here is an example for your long position:

```
tp_per = 5 * 0.01 // 5%
sl_per = 2 * 0.01 // 2%

long_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price + (1 * tp_per)
long_sl_price = strategy.position_avg_price - (1 * sl_per)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Calls Exit", "Buy Calls", stop=long_sl_price, limit=long_tp_price)
```